# Block protect (Keep last line of paragraph with next paragraph)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way to force Microsoft Word 2010 to keep the last line of a paragraph with the next paragraph?

An example of when this is relevant is when starting a block quote; it doesn't look good to have the block quote start at the top of a new page, particularly when it's introduced by a partial sentence, like this:

```
"Lorem ipsum" is sample text widely used in the publishing industry, as the
text has spacing roughly similar to that of English and therefore looks
"normal" but unintelligible to an English reader's eye, allowing the reader
to focus on design elements. It begins,
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
    rhoncus laoreet risus, quis congue leo viverra congue.
    Suspendisse magna massa, viverra imperdiet est eu, ultrices
    volutpat lectus. Sed pulvinar est id risus lobortis venenatis.
```

There shouldn't be a page break after "begins," because it looks like the sentence ends abruptly.

"Keep lines together" won't work, because by definition we're talking about two paragraphs. "Keep with next" won't work if the first paragraph is larger than a couple of lines, because then you get an awkwardly large space at the bottom of the first page. Manual line breaks obviously work, but only when the document is final, which is often less certain than it seems.

I know WordPerfect has [a feature called "block protect" that does this](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T009832_Keeping_Part_of_a_Paragraph_with_the_Next_Block_of_Text.html), but I have not found even an acceptable substitute in Word. I have played with style separators and hidden paragraph breaks, but to no avail.

I would love a special character, kind of like the nonbreaking space or zero width optional space, that tells Word to move to the next page if the next paragraph would otherwise start the page. A macro would also be great, but I haven't been able to find a starting point (like how to detect where non-manual page breaks fall).

**Edit:** It looks like "Keep with next" works this way in Word 2013, but I specifically need a fix that works in Word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Highlight the paragraph, right click and select Format Paragraph. Click on the second tab (I forget the name) and then select Keep With Next. It will keep 2 lines with the next paragraph if the next paragraph starts on the next page.

Keep Together will keep the whole paragraph together. If all paragraphs have this selected, I believe Word will split paragraphs.

Comment: I have already tried playing with that.  Unfortunately, this doesn't achieve what I'm talking about. "Keep with Next" keeps the entire paragraph that has that setting with the next paragraph. I don't want that, particularly if the first paragraph is long. I just want a line (or two, or more as needed) of the first paragraph to stay with the second paragraph.

Comment: P.S. It looks like your answer does work in Word 2013, but not in Word 2010. I use 2010 at work, which is where this is most relevant to me.

Comment: If it takes the whole paragraph, then uncheck Keep Together. For some reason this is a common problem with both of the items being checked. I have used this feature since before 2005.

Comment: "Keep lines together" is not checked, but it still takes the whole paragraph in 2010.

Comment: It will have to wait until I get to work; I don't have Word at home.